# Was there a Proto-Germannic root of "miskunn"

Tags: etymology, semantics, germanic-languages, lexical-semantics, proto-germanic

I was not able to find an etymology of ON "miskunn" within PrG.
Is the first syllable a prefix "mis-" indicating any "wrong kunn, lack of kunn" or a deformed "midi-" as in E "com-passion", G "Mit-leid"?

To which root does the word go back? 
Or did the whole Concept of mercy/Erbarmen first come into Germanic languages with Christianisation?
Wulfila translates Gr "οἰκτίρμων" with "bleiþs" (e.g. Lk 6,36) going back on PrG *bliþiz, which seems less pathetic and weaker.

Comment: I'm not sure what the etymology of _miskunn_ is, but there were certainly Germanic words for the concept; many languages use a descendant of *_mildijaz_.

Comment: Out of interest, what does "seems less pathetic and weaker" mean?

Comment: Kroonen, 2103 translates *bliþa as "mild, kind". To my understanding, E "mercy/mercyful" or G "Erbarmen" has a copletly different Quality: It may be _kind_ of me to offer you a Cup of _mild_ tea. That would be a favour but not a grace. And you would probably never say it's _merciful_ or _erbarmungsvoll_ , since that would presume you respected me being in a position, able to grant or deny you any cup of tea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Bokmålsordboka](https://ordbok.uib.no/perl/ordbok.cgi?OPP=miskunn&ant_bokmaal=5&ant_nynorsk=5&begge=%20&ordbok=begge):

> miskunn m1 (norrøntmisskunn, egentlig 'det å ikke skylde en for noe', -kunn beslektet med kunne med eldre betydning 'skylde') særlig i religiøst språk: (Guds) nåde

A translation into English:

> miskunn *masc* (norse: misskunn, actually "the state of not owing anyone anything", -kunn being related to kunne, having the older meaning "to owe") especially in religious language: (God's) mercy.

That would make it related to Proto-Germanic *kunnaną and PIE *ǵneh₃ or *ǵn̥néh₃ti. I am not sure of the semantic connection between knowing and owing.